# Skip Empty CSV cells for Set-ADUser script

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I've been struggling to figure out the way to fix my script. I'm constantly getting 'Replace' errors for any user that has an empty cell in the CSV.

Example: We have some users that don't have mobile phones. The mobile phone cell for that user will be blank.

The 'Replace' I'm getting is only happening to users that don't have a value for every field.

I've linked the image of the csv columns below.

I've seen a few posts about resolving this, but none seem to match my case. Any help will greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

```
$TestUsers = Import-Csv -Path C:\Users\test.admin\Documents\ADDummyTestUsers.csv


foreach( $user in $testusers )
{ Set-ADUser -Identity $user.sAMAccountName `
 -Title $user.Title `
 -Description $user.Title `
 -OfficePhone $user.TelephoneNumber `
 -MobilePhone $user.Mobile `
 -Fax $user.facismileTelephoneNumber `
 -StreetAddress $user.streetAddress `
 -City $user.city `
 -State $user.st `
 -PostalCode $user.postalCode `
}
```

[csv columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqpy9.png)

Comment: Skip the user completely? Can  you provide a sample of the CSV with, and without blank cells?

Comment: Are you trying to skip if **any** of the values is empty or if `sAMAccountName` is empty?

Comment: What is a 'Replace' error? Can you post such an error message?

Comment: Kindly share the sample csv along with the error message that you are getting.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I've linked the image to the original post.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon samAccountName will never be empty. The only field that would be are mobile phone, and fax.

Comment: Please post the csv in plain text with the fields included

Comment: Your image shows you have a field called `Description` and no field `Title`... Your code uses `Title`, not `Description`, so which is it?

Answer (score 0):

The "Replace" error OP is referring to is something like:

> Set-ADUser : replace At line:15 char:5
>
> - ```
>   Set-ADUser -Instance $User
>   ```
> - ```
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ```
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Set-ADUser], ADInvalidOperationException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser

I'd suggest simply testing for a value before attempting to set it. I've demonstrated this below, while also changing the approach slightly (using instances)

```
$TestUsers = Import-Csv -Path C:\tmp\file.csv

$TestUsers | ForEach-Object {
    $User = $null
    $User = Get-ADUser -Identity $_.samaccountname -Properties description,telephonenumber,mobile,facsimiletelephoneNumber,streetaddress,city,st,postalcode

    if ('*' -like $_.description)              {$User.description              = $_.description}
    if ('*' -like $_.telephonenumber)          {$User.telephonenumber          = $_.telephonenumber}
    if ('*' -like $_.mobile)                   {$User.mobile                   = $_.mobile}
    if ('*' -like $_.facsimiletelephoneNumber) {$User.facsimiletelephoneNumber = $_.facsimiletelephoneNumber}
    if ('*' -like $_.streetaddress)            {$User.streetaddress            = $_.streetaddress}
    if ('*' -like $_.city)                     {$User.city                     = $_.city}
    if ('*' -like $_.st)                       {$User.st                       = $_.st}
    if ('*' -like $_.postalcode)               {$User.postalcode               = $_.postalcode}

    Set-ADUser -Instance $User
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can use the alternate [`-Instance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/set-aduser?view=windowsserver2019-ps#example-5--set-user-properties-to-a-local-instance) on `Set-ADUser`.

```
$TestUsers = Import-Csv -Path C:\Users\test.admin\Documents\ADDummyTestUsers.csv

foreach( $user in $testusers )
{
    $ADUser = Get-ADUser -Identity $user.sAMAccountName

    $ADUser.Title = $user.Title 
    $ADUser.Description = $user.Title 
    $ADUser.OfficePhone = $user.TelephoneNumber 
    $ADUser.MobilePhone = $user.Mobile 
    $ADUser.Fax = $user.facismileTelephoneNumber 
    $ADUser.StreetAddress = $user.streetAddress 
    $ADUser.City = $user.city 
    $ADUser.State = $user.st 
    $ADUser.PostalCode = $user.postalCode 

    Set-ADUser -Instance $ADUser
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first test if a user with that SamAccountName exists (that field in never empty in the CSV file as you say), and if so, build a [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) Hashtable with only attributes that are not empty or whitespace only.
By making use of splatting the parameters to the Set-ADUser cmdlet, you can also get rid of those nasty backticks in your code:

```
$testusers = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\test.admin\Documents\ADDummyTestUsers.csv'

foreach ($user in $testusers) { 
    $ADUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($user.sAMAccountName)'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if (!$ADUser) {
        Write-Warning "User $($user.sAMAccountName) does not exist"
        continue   # skip this one and proceed with the next
    }
    # create a hashtable for splatting
    $splat = @{}
    # only add fields that have content
    if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($user.Title)) {
        $splat['Title'] = $user.Title
        $splat['Description'] = $user.Title
    }
    if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($user.TelephoneNumber)) { $splat['OfficePhone'] = $user.TelephoneNumber }
    if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($user.Mobile)) { $splat['MobilePhone'] = $user.Mobile }
    if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($user.facismileTelephoneNumber)) { $splat['Fax'] = $user.facismileTelephoneNumber }
    if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($user.streetAddress)) { $splat['StreetAddress'] = $user.streetAddress }
    if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($user.city)) { $splat['City'] = $user.city }
    if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($user.st)) { $splat['State'] = $user.st }
    if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($user.postalCode)) { $splat['PostalCode'] = $user.postalCode }

    # now set the properties on the user
    $ADUser | Set-ADUser @splat
}
```